# Shift column of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am new in MongoDB. I have a collection in MongoDB. I would like to shift a column in collection of MongoDB. I would like to place `image` as last column and `email` as before the last column. How can I do that ?

[image]

Comment: What difference does it make? It is just a JSON,  key position does not matter here.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyWinzlet. I am learning mongoDB. That's why I have to know. Thanks.

Comment: Also there are no columns in mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others who mentioned that the order of keys in a document should not matter.

But if you still want to learn more about it, it is mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-field-order) that:

> MongoDB preserves the order of the document fields following write
>   operations...

Considering that, you can actually alter the order of fields by removing and re-inserting them (using `$unset` and `$set`) or by using the [`$rename`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/#up._S_rename) operator which does exactly that. But you will need to do a couple of operations: First rename the `image` field to something else, than re-rename it back to `image` like so:

```
db.test.updateMany({}, {$rename: {image: 'image_'}})
db.test.updateMany({}, {$rename: {image_: 'image'}})
```

Since this will actually re-insert the `image` field, it will cause that field to be last in the document.